# Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'NA' for XML data nested in csv file

Tags: r, xml, csv, lapply, na

I have a data frame in csv format with nested XML data (lists) in some of the cells. I would like to convert the XML lists into data frames, then select two columns from each of the new data frames, and then bind those new data frames together. I can already do most of this using lapply on cells that contain data. The problem is that R returns an error when I include cells that contain `<NA>`.

Some overview:

- the data frame is called "match"
- the column that I'm working with is called "goal"
- cells that contain XML lists are [1729:1733]
- cells that contain < NA > are [1727:1728]
- Note about < NA >:

The code does not actually have any spaces between the brackets and the 'NA', but yes, it does have brackets, as XML does. I wrote it with spaces on here because when I wrote it without spaces, it acts as an actual 'NA'. see here ---> ). Yes I am a noob.

Here are the libraries I'm using:

```
library(XML)<br>
library(plyr)<br>
library(dplyr)<br>
```

Here is the code that I'm using successfully:

```
var1 <- lapply(match$goal[1729:1733], as.character)  
var2 <- lapply(var1, xmlToList) 
var3 <- lapply(var2, ldply, data.frame) 
var4 <- lapply(var3, subset, select = c("player1", "id"))
```

Here is what happens if I try to include cells with < NA > values:

```
gar1 <- lapply(match$goal[1727:1733], as.character)
gar2 <- lapply(gar1, xmlToList)
```

> Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'NA'

1. How do I run this code so that it skips over the < NA >'s?

Here is the data. Sorry it is so messy:

```
match$goal[1727:1733]
```

And the output (sample of the data): 
(Sorry that it came out as an inconvenient one-liner. I'm posting it now, but I'm going to keep messing around to see if I can figure out a better way to display it.

```
[1] <NA> [2] <NA> [3] <goal><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>406</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>22</elapsed><player2>38807</player2><subtype>header</subtype><player1>37799</player1><sortorder>5</sortorder><team>10261</team><id>378998</id><n>295</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>24</elapsed><player2>24154</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>24148</player1><sortorder>4</sortorder><team>10260</team><id>379019</id><n>298</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value></goal> [4] <goal><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>4</elapsed><player2>39297</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>26181</player1><sortorder>2</sortorder><team>9825</team><id>375546</id><n>231</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value></goal> [5] <goal><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>407</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>83</elapsed><player2>30889</player2><subtype>distance</subtype><player1>30853</player1><sortorder>0</sortorder><team>8650</team><id>378041</id><n>344</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value></goal> [6] <goal><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>4</elapsed><player2>36394</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>23139</player1><sortorder>2</sortorder><team>8654</team><id>376060</id><n>244</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>10</elapsed><player2>37277</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>23139</player1><sortorder>1</sortorder><team>8654</team><id>376165</id><n>251</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>411</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>47</elapsed><player2>34466</player2><subtype>volley</subtype><player1>127857</player1><sortorder>3</sortorder><team>8528</team><id>376929</id><n>294</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_ty... <truncated> [7] <goal><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>406</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>47</elapsed><player2>23354</player2><subtype>header</subtype><player1>26165</player1><sortorder>2</sortorder><team>10252</team><id>378837</id><n>251</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>p</comment><stats><penalties>1</penalties></stats><event_incident_typefk>20</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>64</elapsed><player1>40198</player1><sortorder>0</sortorder><team>8456</team><id>378981</id><n>266</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>p</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>69</elapsed><player2>24658</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>23264</player1><sortorder>1</sortorder><team>10252</team><id>379030</id><n>270</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</g... <truncated> 13225 Levels: <goal /> .
```

========================================================================

..

the data, attempt 2 (this is pasted from Excel csv. For this reason the NA's don't have any brackets):

```
rowID   seasonyears match_date_ti   matchid goal
1727    2015/2016   9/27/2015 0:00  1979894 NA
1728    2015/2016   9/26/2015 0:00  1979895 NA
1729    2008/2009   8/17/2008 0:00  489042  <goal><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>406</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>22</elapsed><player2>38807</player2><subtype>header</subtype><player1>37799</player1><sortorder>5</sortorder><team>10261</team><id>378998</id><n>295</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>24</elapsed><player2>24154</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>24148</player1><sortorder>4</sortorder><team>10260</team><id>379019</id><n>298</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value></goal>
1730    2008/2009   8/16/2008 0:00  489043  <goal><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>4</elapsed><player2>39297</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>26181</player1><sortorder>2</sortorder><team>9825</team><id>375546</id><n>231</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value></goal>
1731    2008/2009   8/16/2008 0:00  489044  <goal><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>407</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>83</elapsed><player2>30889</player2><subtype>distance</subtype><player1>30853</player1><sortorder>0</sortorder><team>8650</team><id>378041</id><n>344</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value></goal>
1732    2008/2009   8/16/2008 0:00  489045  <goal><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>4</elapsed><player2>36394</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>23139</player1><sortorder>2</sortorder><team>8654</team><id>376060</id><n>244</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>10</elapsed><player2>37277</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>23139</player1><sortorder>1</sortorder><team>8654</team><id>376165</id><n>251</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>411</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>47</elapsed><player2>34466</player2><subtype>volley</subtype><player1>127857</player1><sortorder>3</sortorder><team>8528</team><id>376929</id><n>294</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value></goal>
1733    2008/2009   8/17/2008 0:00  489046  <goal><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>406</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>47</elapsed><player2>23354</player2><subtype>header</subtype><player1>26165</player1><sortorder>2</sortorder><team>10252</team><id>378837</id><n>251</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>p</comment><stats><penalties>1</penalties></stats><event_incident_typefk>20</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>64</elapsed><player1>40198</player1><sortorder>0</sortorder><team>8456</team><id>378981</id><n>266</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>p</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>69</elapsed><player2>24658</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>23264</player1><sortorder>1</sortorder><team>10252</team><id>379030</id><n>270</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>406</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>74</elapsed><player2>23782</player2><subtype>header</subtype><player1>23264</player1><sortorder>1</sortorder><team>10252</team><id>379074</id><n>283</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>76</elapsed><player2>23782</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>23264</player1><sortorder>1</sortorder><team>10252</team><id>379095</id><n>277</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>90</elapsed><player2>45431</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>46403</player1><sortorder>1</sortorder><team>8456</team><id>379250</id><n>281</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value></goal>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention. I am using R for this problem.

Comment: Can you post all `library` lines? Never assume packages unless using base R. Also, can you post a sample of nested XML data? Can't quite see what you mean about `< NA >` since spaces in XML names are invalid.

Comment: Sorry about that. This is my first stackexchange post.
<br><br>
library(XML)<br>
library(plyr)<br>
library(dplyr)<br>
<br><br>
Regarding < NA >  -  There aren't actually any spaces in there. I wrote it with spaces on here because when I wrote it without spaces (the way it exists in the data), it didn't show up on the screen here. I'm not sure if there is an "escape" character for this, but I couldn't find one.
<br><br>
I'll post a sample of the data in a few minutes...

Comment: first stackoverflow post*

Comment: Thank you again @Parfait. Data has been added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider either subsetting the column for non-NA values or use `tryCatch` in the lapply call:

**Data**

```
library(XML)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

txt = 'rowID   season_years match_date_ti   matchid goal
1727    "2015/2016"   "9/27/2015 0:00"  1979894 "NA"
1728    "2015/2016"   "9/26/2015 0:00"  1979895 "NA"
1729    "2008/2009"   "8/17/2008 0:00"  489042  "<goal><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>406</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>22</elapsed><player2>38807</player2><subtype>header</subtype><player1>37799</player1><sortorder>5</sortorder><team>10261</team><id>378998</id><n>295</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>24</elapsed><player2>24154</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>24148</player1><sortorder>4</sortorder><team>10260</team><id>379019</id><n>298</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value></goal>"
1730    "2008/2009"   "8/16/2008 0:00"  489043  "<goal><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>4</elapsed><player2>39297</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>26181</player1><sortorder>2</sortorder><team>9825</team><id>375546</id><n>231</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value></goal>"
1731    "2008/2009"   "8/16/2008 0:00"  489044  "<goal><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>407</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>83</elapsed><player2>30889</player2><subtype>distance</subtype><player1>30853</player1><sortorder>0</sortorder><team>8650</team><id>378041</id><n>344</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value></goal>"
1732    "2008/2009"   "8/16/2008 0:00"  489045  "<goal><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>4</elapsed><player2>36394</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>23139</player1><sortorder>2</sortorder><team>8654</team><id>376060</id><n>244</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>10</elapsed><player2>37277</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>23139</player1><sortorder>1</sortorder><team>8654</team><id>376165</id><n>251</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>411</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>47</elapsed><player2>34466</player2><subtype>volley</subtype><player1>127857</player1><sortorder>3</sortorder><team>8528</team><id>376929</id><n>294</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value></goal>"
1733    "2008/2009"   "8/17/2008 0:00"  489046  "<goal><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>406</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>47</elapsed><player2>23354</player2><subtype>header</subtype><player1>26165</player1><sortorder>2</sortorder><team>10252</team><id>378837</id><n>251</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>p</comment><stats><penalties>1</penalties></stats><event_incident_typefk>20</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>64</elapsed><player1>40198</player1><sortorder>0</sortorder><team>8456</team><id>378981</id><n>266</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>p</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>69</elapsed><player2>24658</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>23264</player1><sortorder>1</sortorder><team>10252</team><id>379030</id><n>270</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>406</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>74</elapsed><player2>23782</player2><subtype>header</subtype><player1>23264</player1><sortorder>1</sortorder><team>10252</team><id>379074</id><n>283</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>76</elapsed><player2>23782</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>23264</player1><sortorder>1</sortorder><team>10252</team><id>379095</id><n>277</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value><value><comment>n</comment><stats><goals>1</goals><shoton>1</shoton></stats><event_incident_typefk>393</event_incident_typefk><elapsed>90</elapsed><player2>45431</player2><subtype>shot</subtype><player1>46403</player1><sortorder>1</sortorder><team>8456</team><id>379250</id><n>281</n><type>goal</type><goal_type>n</goal_type></value></goal>"'

match <- read.table(text=txt, sep="", header=TRUE, na.strings = "NA")
```

**Non-NA subset Approach**

```
var1 <- lapply(match[!is.na(match$goal), c("goal")], as.character)
var2 <- lapply(var1, xmlToList)
var3 <- lapply(var2, ldply, data.frame)
var4 <- lapply(var3, subset, select = c("player1", "id"))
```

**TryCatch Approach** *(to return an empty `<goal></goal>` for NA values)*

```
var2 <- lapply(match$goal, function(i) {
  tryCatch({ return(xmlToList(as.character(i))) 
    }, error = function(e) return(xmlToList('<goal></goal>')))
})

var3 <- Filter(function(i) nrow(i) > 1, lapply(var2, ldply, data.frame))
var4 <- lapply(var3, subset, select = c("player1", "id"))
```

**If/Else Approach**

```
var2 <- lapply(match$goal, function(i) {
    if(!is.na(i)) 
        return(xmlToList(as.character(i)))
    else
        return(xmlToList('<goal></goal>'))
})

var3 <- Filter(function(i) nrow(i) > 1, lapply(var2, ldply, data.frame))
var4 <- lapply(var3, subset, select = c("player1", "id"))
```

Comment: Thank you @Parfait! This is fantastic. I was able to get the Non-NA subset approach to work quite easily. The other two approaches ran fine, but when I ran var4 <-, it resulted in a "undefined columns selected" error. I'll tinker with those approaches tomorrow to see if I'm putting something in incorrectly. Thank you again.

Comment: Whoops! Not your issue but mine. The last two approaches return empty dataframes from NAs that need to be filtered out. See edit. Also, `tryCatch` is helpful for any other issue like non-xml string, zero-length string, etc.

Comment: As a noob stackoverflow user, I'm not sure to proper etiquette. I just wanted to thank you again. I also wanted to let you know that the edit for the tryCatch() and if/else approaches worked like a dream - even better than !is.na() because they skip over any cells that don't contain the columns I am extracting. @Parfait

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could help in your interesting question. Happy coding!